# Relative Routing not working in canActivate guard

Tags: angular6

```
import { AdminAuthService } from './admin-auth.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router, Route, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AdminAuthGuard implements CanActivate {


    constructor(private _authService: AdminAuthService, private _router: Router, private acRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    }

    canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this._authService.checkValidUser().then((resp) => {
                //let url = state.url.substr(0, state.url.lastIndexOf("/"));
                !resp && this._router.navigate(['../adminlogin'], {relativeTo: this.acRoute});
                //!resp && this._router.navigate([url, "adminlogin"]);
                resolve(resp);
            });
        })
    }
}
```

I am getting following error 
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'adminlogin'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'adminlogin'

The routing code look like

```
{
        path: "admin", component: AdminComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'adminlogin', pathMatch: "full" },
            { path: 'adminlogin', component: LoginComponent },
            { path: 'list', component: ListComponent, canActivate: [AdminAuthGuard] }
        ]
    }
```

Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

It is saying that you don't have any route that matches `adminLogin`, update your canactivate

```
!resp && this._router.navigate(['adminlogin'], {relativeTo: this.acRoute});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't have path that matches with adminLogin.

Please add the following to canActivate method:-

```
this._router.navigate(['adminLogin'], {relativeTo: this.acRoute})
```